# Spring Batch - Is it possible to have a dynamic column in FlatFileReader?

Tags: java, spring, csv, spring-batch

I'm dealing with many CSVs files that don't have a fixed header/column, saying that I can get file1.csv with 10 column and file2.csv with 50 column.

I can't know in advance the number of column that I'll have, I can't create a specific job for each file type, my input will be a black box: bunch of CSV that will have an X number of column from 10 to infinite.

As I want to use Spring Batch to auto import these CSVs, I want to know if it is possible? I know that I have to get a fixed number of column because of the processor and the fact that I need to serialize my data into a POJO before sending it back to a writer.

Could my processor serialize an Array? beside sending one simple Object, can I get an Array of Object and in the end of my job I'll will have an Array of an Array of Object?

What do you think?

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

I arrived to this old post with the very same question. Finally I managed to build a dynamic column FlatFileItemReader with the help of the `skippedLinesCallback` so I leave it here:

```
@Bean
public FlatFileItemReader<Person> reader() {

    DefaultLineMapper<Person> lineMapper = new DefaultLineMapper<>();
    DelimitedLineTokenizer delimitedLineTokenizer = new DelimitedLineTokenizer();
    lineMapper.setLineTokenizer(delimitedLineTokenizer);
    lineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<>() {
        {
            setTargetType(Person.class);
        }
    });

    return new FlatFileItemReaderBuilder<Person>()
            .name("personItemReader")
            .resource(new FileSystemResource(inputFile))
            .linesToSkip(1)
            .skippedLinesCallback(line -> delimitedLineTokenizer.setNames(line.split(",")))
            .lineMapper(lineMapper)
            .build();
}
```

In the callback method you update the names of the tokenizer from the header line. You could also add some validation logic here. With this solution there is no need to write your own LineTokenizer implementation.

Comment: this is useful @pepevalbe. Thanks. Could you also show how you wrote the ItemWriter in the case of dynamic columns.

Comment: Great answer. Thank you.

Comment: How can I use this logic if in my case the header row in not in the 1st position. I.e., my CSV file has some additional rows in the beginning and the actual data header is on row number 16.

Comment: If data before data header row is not neccessary you can just can skip 16 rows. If you need that data I don't think you can use this logic.

Answer (score 4):

Create your own `LineTokenizer` implementation.  The `DelimitedLineTokenizer` expects a predefined number of columns.  If you create your own, you can be as dynamic as you want.  You can read more about the `LineTokenizer` in the documentation here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/file/transform/LineTokenizer.html

Comment: Note that if you use the `DelimitedLineTokenizer`, you can use [setStrict(false)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/file/transform/AbstractLineTokenizer.html#setStrict-boolean-), and this way the number of tokens in the line doesn't have to match the number of defined columns.

Comment: @Michael Minella I managed to solve this without implementing LineTokenizer. Maybe you can give me some feedback