# How Spring Batch can parse dynamic columns based on header names?

Tags: java, spring-batch

I'm trying to implement FlatFileItemReader which can parse csv columns based on header names. Can someone give me idea how can achieve this.

```
@Bean
public FlatFileItemReader<Transaction> csvTransactionReader() {
    FlatFileItemReader<Transaction> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<>();
    reader.setResource(new ClassPathResource("20190306Z_transaction_succeeded.consolidated.csv"));
    reader.setLinesToSkip(1);
    reader.setLineMapper(new DefaultLineMapper<Transaction>() {{
        setLineTokenizer(new DelimitedLineTokenizer() {{
            setNames("txId", "txState", "amount", "currency", "accountHolderName", "merchantTxId");
            setIncludedFields(0, 1, 4, 5, 6, 9);
        }});
        setFieldSetMapper(new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<Transaction>() {{
            setTargetType(Transaction.class);
        }});
    }});
    return reader;
}
```

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: Direct topic: https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-batch/flatfileitemreader-read-csv-example/

Comment: It all depends when you have access to the list of fields you want to read from the header names, when the flatFileItemReader is initialised and when you process the file. There are tricks with pre and post steps where you can save the list of header fields into a job/step context, and these can be read and set onto the fileReader before you process the file content. Again seeing your java code for your job would help.

Comment: now i'm parsing with static columns, but i have to make it dynamic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Batch - Is it possible to have a dynamic column in FlatFileReader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40873311/spring-batch-is-it-possible-to-have-a-dynamic-column-in-flatfilereader)