# How to read csv with unknow column names and with unknow column count using in spring batch?

Tags: spring, csv, spring-batch, inputstream, reader

I have following the FlatFileItemReader configuration for my step:

```
@Bean
@StepScope
public FlatFileItemReader<RawInput> reader(FieldSetMapper<RawInput> fieldSetMapper, @Value("#{jobParameters['files.location']}") Resource resource) {
    var reader = new FlatFileItemReader<RawInput>();
    reader.setName("my-reader");
    reader.setResource(resource);
    var mapper = new DefaultLineMapper<RawInput>();
    mapper.setLineTokenizer(crmCsvLineTokenizer());
    mapper.setFieldSetMapper(fieldSetMapper);
    mapper.afterPropertiesSet();
    reader.setLineMapper(mapper);
    return reader;
}
```

RawInput contains 1 field so it allows me to read csv with single column. For now requirements were changes and now I have to be able to read any csv file with any amount of rows thus instead of RawInput I need to pass array somehow. is it possible with FlatFileItemReader or maybe I should change implementation ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Batch - Is it possible to have a dynamic column in FlatFileReader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40873311/spring-batch-is-it-possible-to-have-a-dynamic-column-in-flatfilereader)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works:

```
    var reader = new FlatFileItemReader<List<String>>();
    reader.setName("reader");
    reader.setResource(resource);
    //line mapper
    var lineMapper = new DefaultLineMapper<List<String>>();        
    lineMapper.setLineTokenizer(new DelimitedLineTokenizer());
    lineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(myFieldSetMapper); // see implementation below
    lineMapper.afterPropertiesSet();

    reader.setLineMapper(lineMapper);
    return reader;


@Component
public class MyFieldSetMapper implements FieldSetMapper<List<String>> {

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public List<String> mapFieldSet(@NonNull FieldSet fieldSet) {
        return Arrays.stream(fieldSet.getValues())
                .map(StringUtils::lowerCase) // optional
                .map(StringUtils::trimToNull) // optional
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to see a good implementation that might help to understand? I got a similar question.

Comment: @JEJC_JACALK it is already an answer. What is your question ?