# How to set target type in Spring batch if CSV format is not fixed in all batch execution cycle?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I am trying read a CSV file using spring batch . I am using FlatFileItemReader. Batch execution is chunk based.
But the issue is CSV format is not fixed in each batch execution cycle.
For example ,
In 1st Cycle- Let's say I have a CSV which has header as id, firstName, LastName.
In 2nd Cycle - It can have header as name, address, salary.
I want to save data for csv in Key-Value pair in one column.(For each row in CSV ,a row will be saved in DB.)
How to implement reader,processer,writer for this?

Reader Class for fixed format i have implemented as below:

```
public class Reader {
  public static FlatFileItemReader<Customer> reader(String path) {
    FlatFileItemReader<Customer> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<Customer>();
 
    reader.setResource(new ClassPathResource(path));
    reader.setLineMapper(new DefaultLineMapper<Customer>() {
      {
        setLineTokenizer(new DelimitedLineTokenizer() {
          {
            setNames(new String[] { "id", "firstName", "lastName" });
          }
        });
        setFieldSetMapper(new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<Customer>() {
          {
            setTargetType(Customer.class);
          }
        });
      }
    });
    return reader;
  }
}
```

For Writer

```
public class Writer implements ItemWriter<Customer> {
 
  private final CustomerDao customerDao;
  
  public Writer(CustomerDao customerDao) {
    this.customerDao = customerDao;
  }
 
  @Override
  public void write(List<? extends Customer> customers) throws Exception {
    customerDao.insert(customers);
  }
}
```

For BatchCOnfig

```
import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Step;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.RunIdIncrementer;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import com.javasampleapproach.batchcsvpostgresql.dao.CustomerDao;
import com.javasampleapproach.batchcsvpostgresql.model.Customer;
import com.javasampleapproach.batchcsvpostgresql.step.Listener;
import com.javasampleapproach.batchcsvpostgresql.step.Processor;
import com.javasampleapproach.batchcsvpostgresql.step.Reader;
import com.javasampleapproach.batchcsvpostgresql.step.Writer;

@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfig {

 @Autowired
 public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

 @Autowired
 public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

 @Autowired
 public CustomerDao customerDao;

 @Bean
 public Job job() {
   return jobBuilderFactory.get("job").incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer()).listener(new Listener(customerDao))
       .flow(step1()).end().build();
 }

 @Bean
 public Step step1() {
   return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1").<Customer, Customer>chunk(2)
       .reader(Reader.reader("customer-data.csv"))
       .processor(new Processor()).writer(new Writer(customerDao)).build();
 }
}
```

Customer DTO is as below

```
public class Customer {
 private long id;
 private String firstName;
 private String lastName;

 public Customer() {
 }

 public Customer(long id, String firstName, String lastName) {
   this.id = id;
   this.firstName = firstName;
   this.lastName = lastName;
 }

 public long getId() {
   return id;
 }

 public void setId(long id) {
   this.id = id;
 }

 public String getFirstName() {
   return firstName;
 }

 public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
   this.firstName = firstName;
 }

 public String getLastName() {
   return lastName;
 }

 public void setLastName(String lastName) {
   this.lastName = lastName;
 }
}
```

[Spring Batch - Is it possible to have a dynamic column in FlatFileReader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40873311/spring-batch-is-it-possible-to-have-a-dynamic-column-in-flatfilereader)
This question is similar to my question but i am unable to understand the answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Batch - Is it possible to have a dynamic column in FlatFileReader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40873311/spring-batch-is-it-possible-to-have-a-dynamic-column-in-flatfilereader)

Comment: Yes. it is similar , but answer is not clear. What is the Person class mentioned in the answer?